# Non selecting group vs look around in regular expression

Tags: regex

What is the difference between `(?:",")([0-9+]+)(?:",,")` and `(?<=",")([0-9+]+)(?=",,")` i seemed to get the same result or I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the same results. In the first one you will get

```
","123123",,"
```

and in the second you will get only

```
123123
```

because in the second case you have only *assertions*.It does not form a part of the match but is a condition for the match.

- `(?<=)` means positive lookbehind
- `(?=)` means positive lookahead

I guess you are only capturing the *group*, so that is the same for both cases as you have captured the same thing. Try printing the complete match instead.

Comment: I  tasted  `","+8801788577733",,"` this in https://regex101.com/#python for these regex got the same result :/

Comment: @NazmulAhasan https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/47 and https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/48

Comment: u didnt put `?:` in the first and last group

Comment: @NazmulAhasan dat just makes a captruing group non capturing.Look at the complete match

Comment: Yes, they're the same in terms of the capture group but not the full match.